# .findbycredentials no response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

My problem is when I make a request to POST /users/login with true data I receive no response instead the catch throw 400

routs file :

```
const express = require("express");
const router = new express.Router();
const User = require("../models/user");

    router.post("/users/login", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(
          req.body.email,
          req.body.password
        );
        // console.log(user);

        res.send({ user });
      } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send();
      }
    });

module.exports = router;
```

user middleware

```
userSchema.static.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });

  if (!user) {
    throw new Error("Unable to find the user");
  }

  const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

  if (!isMatch) {
    throw new Error("uncorect password");
  }

  return user;
};
```

Not all the code here, but I am sure the problem is in these lines,

Comment: shouldnt you import export `findByCredentials` and import it somehwere?

Comment: Can you log the error in catch statement and check it, I can see you are throwing the error from the middleware but not logging it

Comment: TypeError: User.findByCredentials is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In user middleware it should be statics(plural)

```
userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => { 

})
```